# If Field is empty then show certain divs

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following code but it is not working.

Basically I want it so if the field movie_title_2 is empty I want it to add the , but if it is not empty to show just .  I am using wordpress and Advanced Custom Fields plugin.  Thanks!

```
<div class="homepage-opacity">
    <div class="movie-container">
    <?php if (get_field('movie_title_2') && get_field('movie_title_2') != "") { ?>

        <div class="movie-area alone">
            <div class="movie-poster">          
            <?php  if ( get_field('movie_image_poster') ) : ?>
                <img src="<?php the_field('movie_image_poster'); ?>" alt="<?php the_field('movie_image_poster'); ?>}">
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="movie-info">
            <?php
            if(get_field('movie_title'))
            {
                echo '<h1 class="movie-title">' . get_field('movie_title') . '</h1>';
            }
            ?>  
            <?php
            if(get_field('movie_dates_&_times'))
            {
                echo '<p class="movie-times">' . get_field('movie_dates_&_times') . '</p>';
            }
            ?>  
            <?php  if ( get_field('trailer_link') ) : ?>
                <a class="movie-trailer" href="<?php the_field('trailer_link'); ?>" target="_blank">View the Trailer</a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
    <?php if (get_field('movie_title_2') && get_field('movie_title_2') == "") { ?>

        <div class="movie-area">
            <div class="movie-poster">          
            <?php  if ( get_field('movie_image_poster') ) : ?>
                <img src="<?php the_field('movie_image_poster'); ?>" alt="<?php the_field('movie_image_poster'); ?>}">
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="movie-info">
            <?php
            if(get_field('movie_title'))
            {
                echo '<h1 class="movie-title">' . get_field('movie_title') . '</h1>';
            }
            ?>  
            <?php
            if(get_field('movie_dates_&_times'))
            {
                echo '<p class="movie-times">' . get_field('movie_dates_&_times') . '</p>';
            }
            ?>  
            <?php  if ( get_field('trailer_link') ) : ?>
                <a class="movie-trailer" href="<?php the_field('trailer_link'); ?>" target="_blank">View the Trailer</a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="movie-area">
            <div class="movie-poster">          
            <?php  if ( get_field('movie_image_poster_2') ) : ?>
                <img src="<?php the_field('movie_image_poster_2'); ?>" alt="<?php the_field('movie_image_poster_2'); ?>}">
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="movie-info">
            <?php
            if(get_field('movie_title_2'))
            {
                echo '<h1 class="movie-title">' . get_field('movie_title_2') . '</h1>';
            }
            ?>  
            <?php
            if(get_field('movie_dates_&_times_2'))
            {
                echo '<p class="movie-times">' . get_field('movie_dates_&_times_2') . '</p>';
            }
            ?>  
            <?php  if ( get_field('trailer_link_2') ) : ?>
                <a class="movie-trailer" href="<?php the_field('trailer_link_2'); ?>" target="_blank">View the Trailer</a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Comment: When i add content in the field movie_title_2 it does not use the div class movie-area (not with .alone).  It is basically skipping over that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
  <?php 
    $variable = get_field('movie_title_2');

    if ($variable) { ?>

<h1>Add html just like you would normally do</h1>

<?php } else { ?>  

<h1>Add different html here when the variable is empty</h1>


    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I would like to but I am unsure how to add in all the echo's correctly?  I am new to coding/php so I am a little needy :)

Comment: if you found this helpful can you approve the answer.  thanks!